# Django Multilangual Site

Tags: django, django-templates

guys, I want to make a multilingual site but I don't have any idea how to do it and I've some questions. First of all, after I finish my project I did a second template(for the second lang) for every template. Then I change my idea and deleted the second template and make one template for each page using 7 or 8 if-elif-endif. Now I'm really confused about what to do. Does my first try was good and faster or my second is good and faster.
And I have an idea but I don't know is it possible. I want to make 1 template for each page and also at the back end I want to create a dictionary(?) like this:

> en-fr-tr
> hello-bonjour-merhaba as a,
> goodbye-aurevoir-hoscakal as b

and at the templates i just want to write {{dictionary.a}} or {{dictionary.b}}.

For final, I hope you can understand my English, and before finishing I want to add I'm not 100% sure the meaning of the 'template' when I'm saying template I mean .html docs (like index.html and product.html is a template)

Comment: Django has very good support of I18N and L11N. Please, read this [Internalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/#internationalization-and-localization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to create a new template for each language. Just follow the docs on creating language files

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files

index.html

```
{% load i18n %}

<h1>{% trans 'Language' %}</h1>
```

*ja* is the locale_name for Japanese, replace *ja* with the locale_name of your preferred language.

```
django-admin makemessages -l ja
```

This will create a new folder named locale and inside it is another folder named *ja*

> /path/project_name/locale/ja/django.po

```
#: portal/templates/pages/index.html:3
msgid "Language"
msgstr "日本語"
```

If you want to update your template, run this command:

```
$./manage.py makemessages -l ja -i env_name
```

P.S Make sure you turn on the variables needed for localization on your settings.py

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```